# Python, почему при использовании библиотеки Grab, возвращает нужную мне строку и None?

Tags: python, grab

Использую Grab, работаю с DOM, достаю данные из тегов, вот код:

```
from grab import Grab

def scraiping_add():
    # Search link on the foto
    pointer = Grab()
    pointer.setup(timeout=15, connect_timeout=15)
    pointer.go('http://www.photosight.ru/photos/6599649/?from=best')
    response_url_foto = pointer.doc.select('//img[@id = "big_photo"]/@src').text()
    response_text_foto = pointer.doc.select('//img[@id = "big_photo"]/@alt').text()

    print(response_url_foto)
    print(response_text_foto)
```

Первый принт выводит ссылку, а второй строку и None. Как это исправить и почему этот объект появляется?

Comment: Тег `<code>` не нужен для оформления кода.  Подобнее тут: [Как форматировать код в вопросах и ответах?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5860/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%84%d0%be%d1%80%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4-%d0%b2-%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81%d0%b0%d1%85-%d0%b8-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%85)

Comment: Приведенный код, а точнее последняя строчка, выводит только текст. Без всякого второго None.
python --version
Python 3.6.0 :: Anaconda custom (64-bit)
python -c "import grab; print(grab.__version__)"
0.6.38